# Filterrific, trigger submitFilterForm on event from another lib

Tags: filterrific

I'm using Foundation 6 and Filterrific gem in a Rails project. I'd like to trigger the following:

```
$(document).on('changed.zf.slider', Filterrific.submitFilterForm);
```

'changed.zf.slider' is the event that Foundation emits. Filterrific.submitFilterForm is the function I'd like to call. However, it doesn't work even if I bind to the event like this:

```
$(document).on('changed.zf.slider', function() { Filterrific.submitFilterForm() });
```

The code above is defined AFTER Filterrific code is loaded in the browser.

Is this an issue with Filterrific jquery code or should I use a different method for binding to event?

It works fine if I simply copy the original Filterrific.submitFilterForm method body to my binding like

```
$(document).on('changed.zf.slider', function() {
  var form = $("#filterrific_filter"),
      url = form.attr("action");
      $.ajax({...
```

... but it feels like it's not the way to go right? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing here is that `Filterrific.submitFilterForm` depends on `this` context passed to it and looks for the parent `<form>` element.

So you need to call the function with a right context, e.g.:

```js
$(document).on('changed.zf.slider', function() {
  Filterrific.submitFilterForm.call($('#filterrific_filter .slider'))
});
```